# Моя ОС показывает неточное время

Tags: fedora

Я использую Fedora 24. И хоть в настройках и указано время, которое сейчас в моём часовом поясе, виджет "часы" всё равно не хочет показывать точное время.

Comment: У вас автосинхронизация настроена? Часовой пояс верный?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько время не точное? На несколько минут, или на несколько часов?

В первом случае нужно поправить время вручную или настроить ntp-клиент.

Во втором случае нужно указать правильный часовой пояс. И опять-же установить точное время, если в аппаратных часах установлено местное время (а не время по гринвичу (UTC+0)) то установка правильного часового пояса только даст в результате неправильное время.